Simple way to find position number in a given object for a value
So I do, as an example:
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit <blah>

I want to find the position in the array for "Test" (i.e. I want to do some testing where I can refer to the position in the array that $OU.Name -eq "Test" is in, such as $OUs[6]).
I could do with something like:
$number = 0
foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
    "$($OU.name) - $number"
    $number += 1
}

Is there a quicker and easier way?

I misunderstood what you were asking at first, so I deleted my original answers. Hopefully my 3rd attempt is what you are looking for.

Why is it important to get the index?

What should happen if there are multiple OUs matching the criteria? Do you want the solution to find them all, or just the first or last one?

@emanresu, I did edit my question to add bits, so probably my fault, sorry :-).

@SantiagoSquarzon so I can easily run testing - e.g. If I have $OUs, and have a foreach ($OU in $OUs) loop for doing , and there are 40 lines/elements in $OUs, I want to be able to say $OU = $OUs[5] as I know that $OU will cause an error, for example. Sounds a bit garbled even to me though :-)

@Badger You don't need to know the index for that - simply filter the list and then operate only on matching OUs: $OUs |Where-Object Name -eq Test |ForEach-Object { <# $_ now references an OU with name 'Test', work with it in here #> }

@MathiasR.Jessen ah - I didn't frame my question well. The answer below answered my question, but this actually answered the question I SHOULD have asked! I'm annoyed I didn't think of this myself, but, yes, $OU = $OUs | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "test"} gave me what I wanted (but didn't properly ask for). thanks!!

@MathiasR.Jessen That is so funny, that is actually the first answer I posted, but then I deleted it because I thought OP really needed to know the index for a particular reason.

To get just the index of the object with a property name whose value is test you can do this on one line like this:
$object1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name'='test'}
$object2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name'='nope'}
$myArray = @($object1, $object2)
$testIndex = $myArray.IndexOf(($myArray.Where({$_.name -eq 'test'}))[0])

In the above approach, if there is no object with that value then it will return -1. Also note that if multiple objects meet the criteria, this will only return the index of the first item returned. This is due to taking the item at index 0 from the array returned by the Where method.
Or this:
    $object1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name'='test'}
    $object2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name'='nope'}
    $myArray = @($object1, $object2)
    #this will just output the index to the terminal
    $myArray.ForEach({
        if($_.name -eq 'test'){
            $myArray.IndexOf($_)
        }
    })
    #you can capture the index instead, like this:
    $testIndex = $myArray.ForEach({
       if($_.name -eq 'test'){
           $myArray.IndexOf($_)
       }
   })

This also yields -1 when there is no match.

Excellent, thanks! $myArray.IndexOf(($myArray.Where({$_.name -eq 'test'}))[0]) worked like a charm for me.
